# Execution failed for task ':multi_image_picker:parseDebugLocalResources'. cant resolve':multi_image_picker:androidApis'.artifactType android.jar

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, jar

Execution failed for task ':multi_image_picker:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':multi_image_picker:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar.
> > zip END header not found

It's possible that the android jar file is corrupted.

Try removing the android-29 folder from C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\ and then let the IDE download it again.

Download it from Android studio > setting > sdk manager> SDK platforms > check the required option needed then download.

Then

flutter clean

flutter pub get

you can take the build or debugging.

The problem is fixed.